# Spark view engine - passing model to partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, spark-view-engine

It would like to iterate through list and render partial view for each element:

```
<for each="Element elem in elements">
  <render partial="partialViewName">     
</for>
```

How should I pass elem to partial view? <render partial> doesn't have additional parameters. I can use html.RenderPartial, but I would like to use Spark syntax. Is it possible? It looks as if it needed to use the same ViewData and couldn't define its own model.

**EDIT:**

Partial view:

```
${elem.ID}
```

OK. I can use 'elem' in partial view, but partial view doesn't know what type 'elem' is. Of course everything will work, because generated view class compiles, but I have no Intellisense in partial view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<viewdata paramname="paramtype"/>

Also I never used render, I use <use name="partialname" param1="value" param2="value" .../> - maybe it's the same as render, I don't know. But defining your parameters in viewdata as shown above should also work.

Also note the <default /> element, not for this exactly question, but can also be useful since sometimes you'd want some partial parameters to be optional.

Comment: This is the same as render. I prefer render, because its name is more appealing to me. I don't know why I didn't use <viewdata paramname="paramtype"/>, it seems obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't use Spark View Engine. But it appears `<render partial>` **does have** additional parameters. See [here](http://sparkviewengine.com/reference/elements#renderpartial).

So I'm guessing you need to expose a property in your partial view and set its value via [with *="" assignments](http://sparkviewengine.com/reference/elements#withassignments-2).